# special kind of bar plot in R

Tags: r

Imagine that I have the following matrix where every column corresponds to one bar.

```
     1  1  3 
     1  3  1 
     1  2  2
```

I would like to make a stack bar plot where each number would determine a unit block of a different color.

For example if 1=red 2=blue and 3=green I would like to get the following result:

[image: Sorry about the size of the image. Don't know how to change it.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

chartset <- matrix(c(1,1,1,1,3,2,3,1,2), nrow = 3)
chartsetmelted <- data.frame(melt(chartset))

ggplot(chartsetmelted) + geom_tile(aes(x = Var2, y = Var1, fill = factor(value)), width = 0.8)
```

You can look at `scale_fill_manual` to specifically assign colors to values.